# Subroute in NestJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, backend, nestjs

How to create a sub route with Nest ?

I'm trying something like that for `localhost:3000/payment/stripe/get_customer_by_email` :

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import StripeService from './stripe.service';

@Controller('/payments/stripe')
export default class StripeController {
  constructor(private readonly stripeService: StripeService) {}

  @Get('/get_customer_by_email')
  getCustomerByEmail(): string {
    return this.stripeService.getCustomerByEmail();
  }
}
```

But I have a 404 when I launch my e2e test :

```
    expected 200 "OK", got 404 "Not Found"

      19 |     return request(app.getHttpServer())
      20 |       .get('/payment/stripe/get_customer_by_email')
    > 21 |       .expect(200)
         |        ^
      22 |       .expect('Hello Customer!');
      23 |   });
      24 | });
```

Comment: use `'/payments/stripe/get_customer_by_email'` instead of `'/payment/stripe/get_customer_by_email'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your controller you have `payments/stripe` as the route, with the GET as `get_customer_by_email` but in your e2e you're calling `payment/stripe/get_customer_by_email`. `payments` vs `payment` it's a mismatch of the route